# NSTableview cell row overlapping issue

Tags: objective-c, macos, osx-lion, nstableview, overlapping

I have NSTableView in Xib and connected outlet for that.I am loading the cell data using Key value bindings with NSArrayController.I need to fill the cell rows dynamically.I did it.But I am facing the problem,my Tableview cells are getting merged and lines of cell row are not visible.

Why is this happening,How to solve this.Can anybody have ideas please.

It is happening in 10.7.

Comment: Are you refreshing your tableview??

Comment: @hussain He said, that he is using bindings.

Comment: @Akbar: Did you set a row height binding? Can you add a screenshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably due to cells heights in your table are higher that used in TableView by default. If this is your case:

1. Evaluate cell height in IB (row height in Size Inspector)
2. Add delegate method in proper view controller:

   - (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
     {
      return 50.0;   // for example!
     }

Comment: This question is about NSTableview not UITableview